# Angular JS seemingly loses binding to ng-model when selecting drop down value manually

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I have a select control that I'm populating based on a list of objects:

```
<select data-ng-options="obj.QuestionText for obj in jumpToList track by obj.OrderNumber" data-ng-model="questionSelectionJumpTo"
                        data-ng-change="questionDDLChange(questionSelectionJumpTo)" id="ddlJumpTo"></select>
```

In my controller, I'm setting the default value when the modal that contains the drop down list appears by setting questionSelectionJumpTo like this:

```
$scope.questionSelectionJumpTo = $scope.jumpToList[someIndexNumber];
```

This works correctly.

As long as I change the value via the controller, such as when I call a function from a button, and I set `$scope.questionSelectionJumpTo`, it correctly updates the drop down list to show the appropriate option.

However, when I manually change the drop down list by selecting one of the options, the controller can no longer set the selected option using `$scope.questionSelectionJumpTo`.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Can you replicate it  with a demo in a plunker?

Comment: Try removing the data-ng-change. The ng-model by itself can take care of selecting the correct option.

Comment: When you change the select manually, does the value in the controller remain the same or is it undefined or something else? If the value remains the same, it's likely you are dealing w/the usual problems of prototypical inheritance of scopes in Angular.

Comment: Trying to get Plunker to work, but still working on making the code lite enough to give an example.  As for removing the ng-change, I'm using the drop down to dynamically change the content of the modal it's within, using it as navigation, so I don't believe I'd be able to remove the ng-change.  In regards to the model value in the controller remaining the same, it actually correctly changes regardless of whether it's being set programmatically, or via the manual drop down change, but the value is no longer reflected in the control itself once a manual change has been performed.